# Getting Wrong Number of LIKES of Photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

1. Check This Photo http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10150146076506729
   which have more then 40 likes.
2. When i am trying to get LIKES of above photo with /10150146076506729/likes it only returning me 39 LIKES
   instead of more then 40

and also if you Click likes to see users list which likes photo in facebook it is showing only 39 Users Instead of more then 40

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/10150146076506729/likes this what i m using to get LIKES of Photos

Comment: Check now i posted photo example which have less likes

Comment: Could be some kind of caching thing on FB side, perhaps the number of likes is just a rough figure.

Comment: but actually in one photo there is more then difference of 100...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook will Only Return You the Actual No. Of User Likes for Which facebook have information of this Users. For Sure You can Count No. User Likes by Clicking No. Likes..

Answer (score 0):

To only get the total number of likes for photo or any other FB object you can use following FQL query.

```
FB.api({
"method": 'fql.query',
"query": 'SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id="' + ID OF Photo + '"'
}
, function(resp)
{
 totalLikes = resp.length;
}
```

);